# Can I move the order of XCode, Cocoa, and User Templates around in XCode 3.1?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, templates

I followed the other questions on StackOverflow and made custom User Templates.  Instead of replacing the factory default Cocoa class template, I have to pick a new user template.

The order that is shown in XCode's New File dialog box is:

1. iPhone templates first (great if you mostly do iphone development)
2. Second the User templates
3. Third the default Mac OS templates.

I want my user stuff first, Mac OS templates second, and I want to bury iPhone templates in third and last place.  The sort is obviously not alphabetical. And you can't drag/drop reorder. (At least not in xcode 3.1.3)?

[http://lh6.ggpht.com/_13jlf4EjB24/S8Ce3a9IErI/AAAAAAAACSY/qoOVQGHW4FI/s144/Picture%201.png](http://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/6YNUdFWuzqdOKSvOUO792A?feat=embedwebsite)From [stackoverflow](http://picasaweb.google.com/WarrenCanada416/Stackoverflow?feat=embedwebsite)

Comment: OI. I guess the answer is no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can not move them around, unless you work for Apple and have the source code to XCode.